# Can't load a word starting at x+4 address into registry in QtSpim

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, qtspim

I want to load a word from memory ,at adress of x +4 into a registry but the following code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
.data

    x:  .word   10
    y:  .word   11
    z:  .word   12

    .text
    main:
        lw  $t0, x
        lw  $t1, 4($t0)
        li  $v0, 10
        syscall
```

I get an Unaligned Adress in inst/data fetch error and Exception Occured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not loading the address of `x` properly:

```
lw  $t0, x
```

That instruction (actually, it's two instructions, because `lw reg,absolute_address` is a pseudo-instruction) loads the *value* located at `x` into `$t0`. So you get `$t10 = 10`, and then on the next line you try to load from address `10 + 4 == 14`, which of course you can't do because the address needs to be word-aligned.

What you should have used if you wanted to load the *address of* `x` into `$t0` is:

```
la  $t0, x
```